# What are the most difficult words you've learned recently?

Tags: vocabulary

I'd like to ask native speakers of English.

What are some of the most difficult words you've learned recently?
Or what are some of the words whose meanings were elusive and for which you've had to consult your dictionary recently?

Thank you.
I'd like to know a sample of words that trouble even native speakers.

Comment: I'm still having trouble spelling marauder despite having typed it countless times in the past few days.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about subjective value judgements and lists, and seems to come in the category of 'trivia'. And possibly [general reference](http://www.sparknotes.com/testprep/books/newsat/chapter15section4.rhtml).

Comment: Im sorry. Id appreciate it if you could move it there.

Comment: I am not talking about those high schoolers. I am talking about the elite and intelligent folk.

Comment: No – 'general reference' is a reason for a question's non-acceptability here, not another more appropriate forum. You have to do the research yourself, or find a website dealing with this sort of question. [Here](http://www.talktalk.co.uk/reference/dictionaries/difficultwords/data/d0000089.html) is another resource to begin with.

Comment: *Syncategorematic.*

Comment: [This question and its comments](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/26288) contain my answer to your question.

Comment: Surely *supercalifragilisticexpialidocious*.

Comment: Thank you. But these are not practical words. I want to know practical and yet difficult words.

Comment: Surely *mulierast* is both practical and difficult.  Or did you want a *gloss* that were less *quotidian* and more *hemerine*?

Comment: The *subjacent* sentiment seems somewhat *surly*, as ’twere from some *catachrestic churl ejaculated*.

Comment: If you don’t like Latinate terms, here are words more native to the Isle of Britain for landforms and such: *adit air ait bache beck bink born bourne brim brink burn cairn cam
carr close coomb coppice copse croft dale dell dene dess dimble
dingle down dub eyot fell fen firth fold force ford foss frith garth
ghill ghyll gill ginnel glade glen graff groop haugh holm hope how
hurst kame knoll kyle law lea lough low mere midden moor ness pant
pike porth rigg scaur scree shaw side sike skerry snicket sound
stank strath tarn thorpe thwaite toft tor vennel voe vord wheal
wold*.

Comment: **Y'all are going on Santa's naughty list!** :-p  kih1930, this question is really off-topic for this site since it entirely opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

I recently learned the word 'abrogate', meaning to abolish.

Comment: Not to be confused with *arrogate*, although it often is.